# Confused about predict() output from Huggingface Transformers Sequence Classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, huggingface-transformers

Most of the code below is taken from [this huggingface doc page, for tensorflow code selections](https://huggingface.co/transformers/custom_datasets.html). What confuses me is that after fine-tuning a pretrained model on a few new sentences and running `predict` on two test-set sentences, I get `predict()` output that is 16x2 array.

x2 makes sense as I have two classes (0,1), but why length 16 when I passed a test-set of 2 (not 16) sequences, to a 'SequenceClassification' model? How do I get the predicted classes for the two test-set sequences? (ps I have no problem converting from logits to predicted probabilities, just confused about the shape of the output).

Reproducible code example below. Also feel free to step through code in google colab environment [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1pZIRhxlSwuFdPYH2ZuvfL87E58qzGDyy?usp=sharing)

```
from transformers import DistilBertTokenizerFast
from transformers import TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification
import tensorflow as tf

# set up arbitrary example data
train_txt = ['this sentence is about dinosaurs', 'this also mentions dinosaurs', 'this does not']
test_txt  = ['the land before time was cool', 'alligators are basically dinosaurs']
train_labels = [1,1,0]
test_labels = [1,1]

# convert sentence lists to Distilbert Encodings and then TF Datasets
tokenizer = DistilBertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')

train_encodings = tokenizer([str(s) for s in train_txt], truncation=True, padding=True)
test_encodings = tokenizer([str(s) for s in test_txt], truncation=True, padding=True)

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
    dict(train_encodings),
    train_labels
))
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
    dict(test_encodings),
    test_labels
))

# Fine-tune pretrained Distilbert Classifier on our data
model = TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=5e-5)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=model.compute_loss) # can also use any keras loss fn
model.fit(train_dataset.shuffle(1000).batch(3), epochs=3, batch_size=3)

# Generate test-set predictions
test_preds = model.predict(test_dataset)
```

`test_preds` output:

```
>test_preds
TFSequenceClassifierOutput([('logits', array([[ 0.1527334 ,  0.17010647],
                                    [ 0.10007463,  0.15664947],
                                    [-0.10294056,  0.18813357],
                                    [-0.05231615,  0.1587314 ],
                                    [-0.11520502,  0.16303074],
                                    [ 0.00855697,  0.13974288],
                                    [-0.17962483,  0.12381783],
                                    [ 0.05765227,  0.04970012],
                                    [ 0.1527334 ,  0.17010647],
                                    [-0.12754977,  0.11164709],
                                    [-0.00847345,  0.12885672],
                                    [-0.01731028,  0.13520113],
                                    [-0.08433925,  0.16828224],
                                    [-0.20086896,  0.08963215],
                                    [ 0.05765227,  0.04970012],
                                    [ 0.02467203,  0.15794128]], dtype=float32))])
```

Answer (score 0):

The results will be the index of maximum value in each array

Example :

**[ 0.1527334 ,  0.17010647] --> 1  (index of 0.17010647)

[ 0.05765227,  0.04970012] --> 0  (index of 0.05765227)**

So, you can run with next code line:

`class_preds = np.argmax(test_preds["logits"])`

Comment: thanks for the answer but don't think it addresses the key part of my question: "x2 makes sense as I have two classes (0,1), but why length 16 when I passed a test-set of 2 (not 16) sequences"